# How do I mark cells in my sheet for a macro to take values from? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, row

I am trying to build a macro which should insert specified no. of rows below specified row number. Here's what I've tried so far :

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCount As Long
Dim i, j As Long
Dim length As Long

arrVal = Array(2, 3, 4) 'no. of rows to add
arrTar = Array(18, 19, 20) 'target row numbers to respectively add the no. rows specified above
length = 3 'length of above array

For j = 1 To length
    iCount = arrVal(j)
    iRow = arrTar(j)
    For i = 1 To iCount
        Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

The above code is inserting all the rows it's supposed to add (2+3+4=9) directly below first row no. (18). What is wrong with my code? Again, all I want to do is add specified no. of rows below specified row no. (as per arrays in my code, 2 rows below 18th row, 3 below 19th, etc.)

I have just started with loops, so I am pretty confused on what to do here.

Comment: Remember that arrays start at 0, not 1. Also Insert will insert on the specified row, not below. In your case it might seem like below, because it starts at 19, because `arrTar(1) = 19`. Also remember that it will use the current row number, not taking previous inserted rows into account.

Comment: For future reference, `Dim i, j As Long` will dim `i` as a variant, since it's unspecified. Compare with the answer from FaneDuru, where the arrays are variants.

Comment: Many thanks for the tips @ChristoferWeber - would definitely take those into account for future projects of mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code:

```
Sub InsertRows_Arrays()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, iRow As Long, iCount As Long
 Dim arrVal, arrTar, i As Long, j As Long, length As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arrVal = Array(2, 3, 4)    'no. of rows to add
 arrTar = Array(18, 19, 20) 'target row numbers to respectively add the no. rows specified above
 length = UBound(arrVal)    'length of above array, in fact is 2. A 1D array is zero based

 For j = LBound(arrVal) To length
    iCount = arrVal(UBound(arrVal) - j): iRow = arrTar(UBound(arrTar) - j)
    For i = 1 To iCount
        sh.rows(iRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert xlUp
    Next i
 Next j
End Sub
```

1. 1D arrays are 0 based, except the case when you have on top of the module `Option Base 1`. I used `Ubound` to make it working for both cases.
2. What was row 20 before the first insert becomes 22 after first insertions and 27 after the next three. That's why the above code starts insertions from the last array element and of course, uses the correspondent number of rows from the other array...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks a ton @FaneDuru - this works perfectly for me :) I just had one more query, what if I want to insert into rows in a different sheet? Like rows 18/19/20 in Sheet2? How can that be done? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Sonal The sheet where the insertion to take place, does not matter. If instead of `Set sh = ActiveSheet` you will use `Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")` or `Set sh = Sheet2` in case of using sheet `CodeName`, it will work as you want. That's why I used the sheet declaration followed by setting it. To allow such a behavior... :)

Comment: Alright  What if I want to get the no. of rows to add from a cell in `Sheet1`, and insert the no. of rows in `Sheet2` (below specified rows)?

Comment: maybe `For j = UBound(arrVal) To LBound(arrVal) step -1` is more obvious

Comment: @Sonal You should simple proceed as I suggested above, but the array to be built using the cells value you need. Declare and set the other sheet (`sh1`), too. I mean, `Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")` and `arrVal = Array(sh1.range("A2").value, sh1.range("A10").value, sh1.range("A20").value)`, or set a range for each case and place the range value in the array. It can also be loaded in a loop. There are more ways, depending on your real situation...

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, it can be more obvious. I copied his code and only tried to make as less modifications as possible, but making it working. Of course, iterating backwards was a better/clearer solution...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru - Summing up, this was a wonderful solution. You are a life saver :)